# Plupload Html5 preview after Fileselect

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, plupload

http://jsfiddle.net/VjeTk/78/

Using Plupload.com File uploader

i want a preview image after file selection for html5 runtime browsers.

Therefor i add to the FilesAdded Event

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    for (var i in files) {
        $('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + files[i].id + '">' + files[i].name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(files[i].size) + '<img src="' + SOMEHOWLOCALSOURCEOFIMAGE +'"/>') <b></b></div>';
    }
});
```

Problem is Plupload does not deliver the usual binary file object like html does.
Thanks for ANY help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Plupload 2 has an image object, which you can use:
https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/wiki/Image

`File.getSource()` and `mOxie.Image.embed()` are the methods, you are interested in.

https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/wiki/File#wiki-getSource--method

https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/wiki/Image#wiki-embed-eloptions-method

The jQuery UI queue widget uses this.

Here's a working example for a custom uploader:
http://jsfiddle.net/wo9rc54a/

Works even in browsers that don't support HTML5 File API (yes, even IE6).

Comment: I don't get why the "file.destroy()" is used on the "onembedded" but it causes errors when sending multiple images (version 2.1.8). I removed that bit and it worked fine.

Comment: FYI, moxie does not upload GIFs.

Comment: @sandraqu moxie uploads GIFs, it's just that it doesn't consider them being images.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showImagePreview( file ) {
 var reader = new window.FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(file.getNative());
 reader.onload = function () {
  base64data = reader.result;
  base64data = base64data.substring(base64data.indexOf(",") + 1);
   var base_64_url = "data:" + file.type + ";base64," + base64data;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternative `showImagePreview` (Withour mOxie)

Answer (score 0):

`file.getNative()` seems to be broken in version 3*

See: https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/1560

But this solution from https://github.com/shinn-lancelot works perfectly

```js
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        console.log('data url: ', reader.result);
        document.getElementById('image-preview').src = reader.result;
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0].getSource().getSource());
});
```