# Plupload preview image appears upside down or sideways when uploading images taken from mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload, plupload

I'm using Plupload 2.1.9, the core API
I'm displaying a preview of the image before upload, some of the images appears upside down or sideways

I did a LOT of googling about the issue, from stackoverflow to github ... forums, got not where

So i did a test in the examples section on the plupload website in the UI Widget, same issue

[Plupload Example on the plupload website (UI Widget)](http://www.plupload.com/examples/)

If you try the demo from your mobile, you'll notice the preview image doesn't show with the correct orientation

I would like to mention, that in my application, even that the preview appears upside down, once uploaded, it's uploaded with the correct orientation, (since i set preserve_headers: false in the plupload options)

[Preview before upload on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om2KP.png)

The images that appears in the wrong orientation, are from a mobile phone, resizing them on the computer, works fine.

Some research mentioned about the exif data in the image, but that got me now where

Here's a sample of my code:

```js
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
 
        //maximum number of allowed files to add
        max_files = 5 - nb_images;
                     
        if (up.files.length > max_files) {
            up.splice(max_files);
        }
 
        $.each(files, function(i, file){
             
            img = new mOxie.Image();
 
            img.onload = function() {
 
                 thumb_wrapper = $('<div/>', { class: 'thumbnail pull-left', id: file.id }).appendTo('#files');
 
                $("#files .thumbnail").css("position", "relative");
 
                this.crop({
                    width: 120,
                    height: 120,
                    preserveHeaders: true
                });
 
                this.embed(thumb_wrapper.get(0), {
                    /*width: 120,
                    height: 120,*/
                    crop: true
                });
 
                //initialize the remove button
                 removeBtn = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='img-del' style='background: #CC0000; color: #FFF; width: 25px; height:25px; position:absolute; right:4px; padding-top: 3px;'>";
 
                removeBtn = removeBtn + "<strong>X</strong>";
 
                removeBtn = removeBtn + "</a>";
 
                $("#" + file.id).append(removeBtn);
 
            };
 
            img.onembedded = function() {
                this.destroy();
            };
 
            img.onerror = function() {
                this.destroy();
            };
 
            img.load(this.getSource());   
             
        });
         
    });
```

Changing the preserveHeaders to false, won't make a difference

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this might help somebody who has the same issue and i hope the developers for the Plupload debug the issue

After some research, I fell on this stackoverflow link:

[Plupload Html5 preview after Fileselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339899/plupload-html5-preview-after-fileselect)

which led me to the jsfiddle in the answer:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/Ec3te/2/][2]
```

where the preview appears in the correct orientation by testing with the same pictures i was using before to upload and had the orientation issue with.

Noticed that the version of the plupload.full.min.js file in the jsfiddle is: v1.2.1 while the one that comes with the plupload v2.1.9 has the version: 1.3.5

Switched those file it's solved my preview orientation problem

Hoping in the next release of the plupload this will be fixed

Regards,